# Как просмотреть событие, назначенное с помощью addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, html5, frontend

Я хотел бы просмотреть событие, зарегистрированное с помощью `element.addEventListener`. Как это сделать?
Желательно без полифиллов и обёрток.
Мне обязателен код обработчика.

Comment: дайте больше деталей. Просмотреть событие - что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Если момент самого события.... то в функции есть (event) его можно вывести в консоль и посмотреть все интересующее в момент события.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял подоплеку вопроса, речь о том чтобы получить эти сведения через `JS` а не `devtools`. Плохая новость в том что это не возможно.

```js
document.querySelector('#test2')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('test2')
}, false)

document.querySelector('#output1').innerText = document.querySelector('#test1').onclick

document.querySelector('#output2').innerText = document.querySelector('#test2').click
```

```html
<button id="test1" onclick="console.log('test1')">test1</button>
<pre id="output1"></pre>
<button id="test2">test2</button>
<pre id="output2"></pre>
```

Есть конечно обходной вариант - сделать обертку над `addEventListener` на все элементы например через `querySelectorAll('*')` до того как отработают другие скрипты, это может подойти для тестирования своего кода, но вряд ли подойдет в других случаях. А иным способом сделать это не возможно, так как там нативный код.

```js
// сохраняем оригинальную функцию 
const old = document.querySelector('#test3').addEventListener

document.querySelector('#test3').addEventListener = function(){
  console.log(arguments[1])
  old.apply(this, arguments) // вызываем оригинальную функцию
}

document.querySelector('#test3')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('test3')
}, false)

document.querySelector('#output3').innerText = document.querySelector('#test3').click
```

```html
<button id="test3">test3</button>
<pre id="output3"></pre>
```

И третий самый героический путь, смотреть исходники `devtools` как это там реализованно и писать свое расширение которое будет взаимодействовать со страницей или еще как-то выводить информацию о событиях.

Answer (score 5):

В devtools, выберите элемент, рядом со вкладкой стили есть вкладка Event Listeners, там вы можете увидеть все слушатели, которые вы добавили на элемент.

[image: Вкладка]